# How to setup and configure perfect webserver on centos for magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, varnish, php-7.3, webserver

I want to Build a new AWS EC2 centos webserver with the best configuration for Magento2 ?

there is any clear steps or script?

Regards,
Ahmed

Comment: is it PROD or DEV environment you're referring at? in any case it depends on what your needs/objectives are. perfect configuration is a wide thing to think at as it consists of many aspects such as: performance, security, scalability just to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

The basic steps is to use it via nginx or httpd and mysql for database

for more configuration its depends on your traffic and your magento store.

thanks

Comment: To add to this how much you are prepared to spend

Answer (score 0):

as you asking for a script, you can test this one:

https://magenx.sh

```
curl -LO magenx.sh/magenx.sh
```

it is not the best/perfect but you can look at different angle.
but perfect and best it all depends on your skills.
if you know about webstack you can build anything you need.